# Firefox not working past opening

Tags: firefox

Firefox is not working/responding after I open it.  No buttons will work.  It has been updated twice plus an uninstall and install.  I am on PinguyOS 10.10 64bit.  The same Firefox is working on Ubuntu 10.04 32bit and Windows7 32 bit.  After install, Firefox was the same including my custom addons, should it not be a clean install?  Install was done thru synaptic.  The OS has been shutdown with no help for Firefox.

Comment: Strictly speaking - this should be migrated to the Unix Stackoverflow since the OP is not using an official ubuntu derivative.

Comment: Try (re)moving your profile and restarting without one...

Answer (score 1):

Could be your video driver messing up the new Fx hardware acceleration function that's turned on by default.  Especially likely if you use ATI proprietary driver.

The way to turn it off is:

1. Enter firefox using safe mode (`firefox --safe-mode`)
2. Goto Preferences -> Advanced
3. Under General tab, Browsing section, there's the hardware acceleration option
4. Uncheck it and restart

That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I am not having this  issue on the other OS/partitditons on the laptop.  Has been like this since  firefox 6. will try safe-mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try starting firefox from a terminal if you haven't to see if you get any useful errors. strace firefox may help too.

Also as already mentioned try renaming your profile so you start with a clean one to see if the issue is in your profile.